# Can't get getElementsByTagName to work correctly

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a JavaScript that alternates the color of each row in multiple tables. The catch is that some tables aren't going to  be altered at all. So, I'm trying to use this code to get the rows of the table:

```
function alternateRows(myTable)
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table").getElementsByClassName(myTable).getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

And, in the HTML:

```
<body onload="alternateRows('myTable')";>
  <table class="myTable">
```

I can get it to work just fine if I use the id attribute and change the JavaScript to:

```
var rows = document.getElementById(myTable).getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), thats why it called getElements not getElement. a NodeList does not have the "getElementsByClassName" method defined, that's the error you should see.

You'll need to use loops. Also know that you can use CSS selectors for this, all modern browsers support this except IE 8 and lower.

CSS for modern browsers (or IE8- with e.g. a helper library, like [ie9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/))

```
table.mytable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: black;
}
table.mytable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: So then how do you get a particular class from a tag?

Comment: @user2198320: I believe I showed this in my answer. The property is called `.className`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className.

Comment: Oh ok I see. What do I do if I can only use classes and no id's?

Comment: @user2198320: Did you actually have a look at my answer or is it not explained well enough?

Comment: Yeah, I checked out the site and I'm new to JS so its taking me a bit to comprehend everything. So since getElementsByTagName sends back a NodeList, I have to loop through that array and check each table tag for the particular class?

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of DOM methods:

1. Methods which return a reference to a single node. For example [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) and [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelector).
2. Methods which return **a list** of nodes. For example, [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).

Those methods which return a list of nodes usually return a [`NodeList` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) object, which has a very limited interface. All you can do with it is access the single elements in the list, just like an array, it does **not** have the same interface as a DOM node (or element).

If you want to call further DOM methods or DOM properties on the elements in the list, you can either access a specific node directly with its index, or *iterate* over the list and do so for each element:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    // do something with elements[i]
}
```

Note that `NodeList`s are usually *live*, which means any changes to the DOM (e.g. removing a `div` element) will update the list automatically.

---

In your particular situation, you have to options:

1. Use `querySelectorAll` to select all rows:

   ```
   var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table.' + myTable + '  tr');
   ```
2. or iterate over the selected elements:

   ```
   var rows = [];
   var tables  = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
   for (var i = 0, l = tables.length; i < l; i++) {
       // check whether it is a table with class in the variable `myTable`
       if ((' ' + tables[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + myTable + ' ') > -1) {
           rows = rows.concat(tables[i].getElementsByTagName('tr'));
       }
   }
   ```

   Instead of selecting the elements by tag name and then test their class, you could directly use `getElementsByClassName` instead, but it is not as widely supported as `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use only by `getElementsByTagName` or by `getElementsByClassName`
Like:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

or

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

or use `querySelectorAll`

**Syntax:**

`var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.note, div.alert");`

In your **example:**

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table."+myTable).getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

`getElementsByTagName` gives array so you should use it with `zero index`
Same for `getElementsByClassName`

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName
And 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the first way did not work. I did try without the getElementsByTagName and it worked but not when I try multiple tables.

Comment: @user2198320 yes,you are right. It will work with `getElementsByTagName` or by `getElementsByClassName`, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your tables must be modified in same way, you can use following code:

```
var tables = document.getElementByTagName("table");
for (var i in tables)
{
    var rows = tables[i].getElementByTagName("tr");
    //Alternating code here
}
```